# Moving layer causes physics object to stay in place

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm fiddling around with cocos2d v3 in combination with sprite builder.

The game is a simple catch and avoid game, objects coming down an the hero is standing in the bottom of the screen and you can move him around with the accelerometer.

I have a level file (cclayer) with some objects (ccnode) in it, the have physics enabled. 
In my update function I move the layer slowly down.

If the objects have physics enabled, they just drop down. If I switch it to statics physics, they stay in place.

The only way I can find to move the object along with the layer is to turn off the physics completely. But then the collisions won't work anymore...

This kept me buys for the past 4 hours or so.

What is the best approach for this situation?

Thanks in advance guys!

this is my update function:

```
    - (void)update:(CCTime)delta {


float maxX = winSize.width - _hero.contentSize.width/2;
float minX = _hero.contentSize.width/2;


CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData = _motionManager.accelerometerData;
CMAcceleration acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;
CGFloat newXPosition = _hero.position.x + acceleration.x * 1000 * delta;
newXPosition = clampf(newXPosition, minX, maxX);
_hero.position = CGPointMake(newXPosition, _hero.position.y);



//level position

CGPoint oldLayerPosition = _levelNode.position;

float xNew = oldLayerPosition.x;
float yNew = oldLayerPosition.y -1.4f;

_levelNode.position = ccp(xNew, yNew);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a design decision made within the physics engine. **Physics bodies do not move with their parents.** See: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/issues/570

You need to change the design of your game so that your hero moves, and the obstacles stay in the same position. Then you implement a camera like mechanism to follow your moving hero.

We have used the same approach in our [flappy bird tutorial](https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/369/build-your-own-flappy-bird-with-spritebuilder-and).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that did the trick indeed!
The only problem I still have that the collisions do not fire unless i have gravity enabled on the objects. 
And I can of course set the gravity to 0,00 on the Physicsnode, but then the collisions won't fire as well. 

I must be something simple, but can't seem to find out it what :-(

Thanks for you help again!!

Comment: I just accepted your answer. 
This is the version I currently have: cocos2d-iphone version 3.0.alpha

Comment: Ok, the newest version is RC3. You could try to switching to that and see if that resolves the problem.